# Not able to change status bar color for few screens in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme, android-statusbar

I've got an application below for which I want to change color of display bar which is all right for MainActivity screen but for all other activity screens it is displayed as white, see in below picture:

[image]

Following is my style.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>  
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.kushal.boulders">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_authentication"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.RegistrationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_registration"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.UserProfileActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_userprofile"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MemberProfileActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_member_profile"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.AddMemberActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_addmember"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.EditMemberProfileActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_editmember"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.AboutActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**AddMemberActivity.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.kushal.boulders.activities.AddMemberActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_amf_greenArea"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_amf_greyArea"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view_amf_greenArea"
        android:background="@color/colorGrey"/>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_addMember"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/rl_mainLayout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_save" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_mainLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:elevation="12dp">


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cv_amf_memberAvatar"
                style="@style/MemberItem_CardViewStyle"
                android:layout_width="124dp"
                android:layout_height="124dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                app:cardCornerRadius="60dp"
                app:contentPadding="2dp"
                android:elevation="10dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cv_amf_memberAvatarHolder"
                style="@style/MemberItemAvatarHolder_CardViewStyle"
                android:layout_width="118dp"
                android:layout_height="118dp"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                app:cardCornerRadius="60dp"
                app:contentPadding="2dp"
                android:elevation="10dp">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_amf_memberAvatar"
                    android:contentDescription="Member Profile Picture"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_member" />


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_rotateImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                app:fabSize="mini"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorGrey"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_rotateright" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_amf_addImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:fabSize="mini"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_new_member"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/fab_rotateImage"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorGrey"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom" />


        </RelativeLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
                app:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
                app:contentPadding="2dp">

             <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
                app:contentPaddingBottom="15dp"
                app:contentPaddingLeft="15dp"
                app:contentPaddingRight="15dp"
                app:contentPaddingTop="15dp">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                    android:paddingRight="20dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp">

                    <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lbl_amf_memberFirstName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="First Name"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:drawablePadding="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"/>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edt_amf_memberFirstName"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"/>
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lbl_amf_memberLastName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Last Name"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:drawablePadding="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    />

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edt_amf_memberLastName"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"/>
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lbl_amf_memberPhone"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Phone"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_phone"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_phone"
                        android:drawablePadding="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                        />

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edt_amf_memberPhone"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
                            android:inputType = "phone"/>
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lbl_amf_memberEmail"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Email"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_email"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_email"
                        android:drawablePadding="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"/>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edt_amf_memberEmail"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"/>

                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lbl_amf_memberAddress"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Address"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_address"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_address"
                        android:drawablePadding="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"/>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edt_amf_memberAddress"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"/>
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lbl_amf_memberCycleStartDate"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Cycle Starting on"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_date_start"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_date_start"
                        android:drawablePadding="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"/>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/holder_amf_memberCycleStartDate"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edt_amf_memberCycleStartDate"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
                            android:focusable="false"/>
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lbl_amf_memberCycleEndDate"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Cycle Ending on"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_date_end"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_date_end"
                        android:drawablePadding="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"/>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/holder_amf_memberCycleEndDate"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edt_amf_memberCycleEndDate"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
                            android:focusable="false"/>
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

             </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: post your manifest also

Comment: why are you using different themes if you are using same values for properties?

Comment: @RajasekaranM : updated my question

Comment: @kushal.8 please add `AppTheme.NoActionBar`? because it's may be theme issue

Comment: @RajasekaranM I've added , you can see in manifest

Comment: can your show me your `AppTheme.NoActionBar` style?

Comment: @kushal.8 can u please tell me in which activity your status bar color is not changed and in which  what is theme of that actvity

Comment: @NileshRathod: For all other activities in my manifest color is not changed, check my manifest.json in question

Comment: @kushal.8 
Test case just make `CoordinatorLayout` in those as root layout and than check

Comment: @NileshRathod : id there no other alternative?

Comment: @NileshRathod : I tried for MemberProfileActivity with coordinator layout but still getting the same

Comment: Please edit your question to include the `<style>` definition for your `AppTheme.NoActionBar` theme.

Comment: @BenP. I've added It in style.xml section

Comment: @kushal.8 are you using android:fitsSystemWindows="true" in root layout

Comment: @Lokesh : I've `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` for Main Activity, where everything looks ok

Comment: ok then try with that activity that status bar not show

Comment: tried adding android:fitsSystemWindows="true" for other activity, not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that you are not overriding `<item name="android:statusBarColor">` in `style.xml`. After that it is better to use `CoordinatorLayout` together with `AppBarLayout` in each activity's layout. Try to define `AppTheme.NoActionBar` style as following:

**style.xml**

```
...

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

In each activity, define root layout and toolbar as below snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="path.to.Activity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- include content here with match_parent width and height -->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

At the end, in `manifest.xml` set `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` to whole application (in application tag) and override it for every activity which should use different theme.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.kushal.boulders">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_authentication"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.RegistrationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_registration"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.UserProfileActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_userprofile"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MemberProfileActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_member_profile"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.AddMemberActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_addmember"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.EditMemberProfileActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_editmember"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.AboutActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: @kushal.8: Have you tested `CoordinatorLayout ` together with `AppBarLayout` as I mentioned?

Comment: Please post your activity layout in question.

Comment: check `AddMemberActivity.xml`  in my update question

Comment: I have tested your configuration in a new project and the status bar color shows correctly. By taking a look at the picture included in question, we can see that the back button icon has dark color which means that there is problem with style in this activity. If it is possible, you can share your project in a private gitlab repository and add me to it. I can check your base source code.

Comment: I'll check it today.

Comment: @kushal.8: I have found the problem. You are overriding the `AppTheme.NoActionBar` in `values-v21/styles.xml` and setting `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>` in it. Please remove this, I mean remove `AppTheme.NoActionBar` from `values-v21/styles.xml` because it does not override anything in `AppTheme.NoActionBar` from `values/styles.xml`.

Comment: Thanks @aminography for your insight, I will take a look later today and let you know.

Comment: Yes It worked, Would be better if you could nclude in your answer so it would be useful for people facing this issue in future.
Thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
AppTheme.NoActionBar
```

With the code. you can also select the same form layout theme options, it will do all the style code change.